# Link in drop down HTML menu not working

Tags: html

The link for Drop down 1 and 2 does not want to work.
The page with this code is http://www.lansdownesdachurch.co.za/index.html
I have left the drop down menu visible while trying to sort out this problem.

```
<nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop down 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop down 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="OurBeliefs.html">Our Beliefs</a></li>
            <li><a href="BibleStudy.html">Bible Study</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is not a do my home work forum

Comment: the question is unclear. what do you mean by link? href is empty for them.

Comment: I am not looking for people to do my homework, I am studying html5 and css3 via correspondence and have no lectures to attend. I depend on a text book and youtube videos. I have no previous experience so this is all new to me. I am just an extreme novice...we all have to start somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In your href of drop down, put the name of your html page instead of #

For example, if drop down 1 must redirect to books and drop down 2 to sea:

```
  <li><a href="book.html">Drop down 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="sea.html">Drop down 2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **href** attributes are empty, you need to point them to html file you want to open, I'd go with relative URL in your case to keep it simple. You can read more details on drop-down menus [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp).

Comment: Even if I add a html file to the <a tag (which I have done now) it still does not read the <a tag as a link, although the very same html file reads as a link when it is not part of the ul than is inside the li

Comment: Just realized that the links work in Firefox but not in Chrome....how do I fix that

Comment: Hmm, sometimes Chrome has this issues, try adding z-index to your .nav { z-index: 9999; }